# Didn't get the Data Stored in Shared Preference from Native side to Flutter Module

Tags: android, flutter

I want to save the data in Shared preference from Android native side and retrieve from the Flutter module added in it

On Native side, For store the data

```
with (sharedPreferences.edit()) {
            putInt("Data", 5)
            commit()
```

On Flutter side for retrieve data

```
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
result =  (prefs.getInt('Data') ?? 0);
print('Result: $result times.');
var success= await prefs.setInt('counter', result);

print('success $success');
return success;
```

Comment: Getting same problem Shared Preference data getting null when try to get in flutter module the key and mode is same.

Comment: Can you tell me your `context#getSharedPreferences` call from android side?

Comment: @ShababbKarim  this is in the onCreate of Activity
sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

Comment: @Amit what is the value of `PREF_NAME` ?

Comment: @ShababbKarim     private val PREF_NAME = "data"

Comment: I think your PREF_NAME value needs to be "FlutterSharedPreferences", not "data". Can you try it out?